# Resize content with window in FXML (JavaFX)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml, window-resize

How do you get the new window size after resizing by user in FXML (JavaFX)? I have searched for a "onResizeWindow" method but I found nothing.

I have a simple `Pane` and I want it resize itself when the user resize the window. And how do you resize ToolBar with the Pane?

Here is my FXML code:

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testJavaFXML.Controller">
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="200.0" left="200.0" right="200.0" top="200.0" />
   </padding>
   <children>
      <ToolBar prefWidth="600.0">
        <items>
            <Button fx:id="buttonPlay" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePlayButtonAction" text="Play" />
            <Button fx:id="buttonPause" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePauseButtonAction" text="Pause" />
            <Button fx:id="buttonStop" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleStopButtonAction" text="Stop" />
        </items>
      </ToolBar>
      <Label fx:id="labelHelloWorld" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="187.0" text="Hello World!" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

I found how to do this: I must use a `StackPane` which includes the `Pane`, like that:

```
<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <ToolBar prefWidth="600.0">
              <items>
                  <Button fx:id="buttonPlay" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePlayButtonAction" text="Play" />
                  <Button fx:id="buttonPause" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePauseButtonAction" text="Pause" />
                  <Button fx:id="buttonStop" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleStopButtonAction" text="Stop" />
              </items>
            </ToolBar>
         </children>
      </Pane>
       <Label fx:id="labelHelloWorld" text="Hello World!" />
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the width and height of the stage:

```
stage.widthProperty().addListener((ov, oldWidth, newWidth) -> someAction);
```

But a better approach would be to use an appropriate LayoutPane e.g. [BorderPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) which handles the resizing